# Lua expected = near data

Tags: lua

```lua
local file = 'data.txt'
local lines = lines_from(file)

global data = {} -- this line is giving the error "lua: day8.lua:20: '=' expected near 'data'"

for key, value in pairs(lines) do
  local row = {}
  for i=1, #value do
    local char = value:sub(i,i)
    row[i] = char
  end
  data[key] = row
end
```

As you can see from the code above, my code is throwing an error on the line where the variable `data` is initialised. This code was working earlier when I tested it, then I added more code below what is visible and it broke this line somehow.

I don't think its the code below that broke this line as otherwise why would it be showing there?

This is also my first ever code with lua so I have no experience with this language.

What could be wrong in this code that could cause this error

Comment: The syntax highlighting of the code should give a pretty strong indicator of what is wrong. keywords are rendered in blue, and `global` is not blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables don't need to be declared explicitly like `local` ones do. The interpreter is erroring because you are prefixing `global` to your variable, which isn't a recognized keyword

Try the following, without the `global`:

```
data = {}
```